# Not receiving BroadcastReceiver when device is locked

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, locked

I have an activity(caller screen) which popups when device is locked.
There is a BroadcastReceiver registered on this activity oncreate method.

```
context.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("CallEnded"));
context.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("CallAccepted"));
```

My BroadcastReceiver not receiving when device is locked. But it works when device is unlocked.

Here's how I send the Broadcast.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("CallEnded");
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

And here's how I define my activity to show up when the device is locked.

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                +WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                +WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

Can anybody help me out please?

Comment: if you are using broadcast to communicate within your app, then you can try using `LocalBroadcast`

Comment: Thank you so much. LocalBroadcast fixed my issue.